# Android remove x86 and x86_64 support for existing app

Tags: android, x86, arm, x86-64, 32bit-64bit

I have an android app which currently supports both intel and arm architectures. I am planning to remove `x86` and `x86_64` support. I have tried to install the apk generated in x86 emulator and verified that my app is not supported. But how would this reflect in playstore for someone with an `x86` device? If someone with `x86` device had already installed my app, would they see an update in playstore? If someone with `x86` device, who hasnt installed my app before, what would they see in playstore?

Comment: I'm curious about the reason you want to drop the x86-family support? Do you have some native or even assembly code that you don't want to support anymore for the x86 family?

Comment: _"what would they see in playstore?"_ Can't you create an x86 emulator image that includes Google Play and then visit the Play store in that emulator?

Comment: Is it worth supporting x86? Maybe rejection from x86 it step to future.